# How can I avoid paying for costly material components?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, spell-components

Create Magic Tattoo (SC p55) looks like a great spell, but it is very pricy at 100gp per casting. Is there a way to avoid/reduce the cost?

The solution should be official, at least from *Dragon* magazine.
I am interested in things available at level 7, and costing less than 3000gp.

*"Don't cast the spell"* is not an acceptable answer.

Comment: I suppose, because of its largely unplayable nature, likewise unacceptable is the epic feat  [Ignore Material Components](http://dndsrd.net/epicFeats.html#ignore-material-components) (*EL* 57)? What about semiofficial (i.e. magazine and Web), licensed, and third-party material?

Comment: @HeyICanChan, I always forget these boundary conditions.

Comment: Hmm...  I started to answer this, then remembered that Paizo stuff for 3.5 isn't considered official. If you're willing to consider "printed in a module by a company that took up the 3e torch and printed 'Pathfinder - DnD 3.75e' two years later" official enough, I have an answer for you then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to mimic Create Magic Tattoo with Shadow Conjuration. It isn't described to the full extent, but Shadow Conjuration is probably intended to duplicate an effect of a spell not a spell itself, so you shouldn't be obliged to provide material components for it to work. I also recommend to ask your DM, how does she or he handle disbelieve in this case.

Given the large amount of material issued for the system, there definitely may be more ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The Hat of Many Spells is a piece of equipment that was canonically wielded by Presto, a D&D character who started with it at 1st level and used it through 7th level, at least.

Among other abilities, it can provide any spell components needed for spellcasting up to 1,000gp in value.

Given that the market value of the hat was set at 25,000gp, that is beyond the 19,000 wealth by level of a 7th level character.

Thus at 7th level, DM fiat would likely be the only way to acquire it, the same way the original character literally acquired it. Might be useful to your character in the near future?

Comment: Is Presto from a published adventure?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Presto and his friends' magic items were published for *D&D 3.5* in the [*Animated Series Handbook*](https://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/57403/animated-series-handbook), a WOTC official (if tiny) hardback included with the initial pressing of the DVD set. I kid you not.

Comment: The downside is you have to face Tiamat as your first encounter.